Regex Generic Formulas: Find something between two entities (two strings)
I have this case:
<p class="text_obisnuit">2. And you can customize the vision according to the meaning that people give to it. their lives?<br>
</p>

I want to find any <br> that is located between <p class="text_obisnuit"> and </p> , after that to replace it with </p>
i.e. to become like this:
<p class="text_obisnuit">2. You can customize the vision according to the meaning that people attach to it. their lives?</p>
My regex finds and replaces <br> with </p> but there is still a </p> on the bottom line. So it is not very good.
FIND: (?s-i)(?:<p class="text_obisnuit">|(?!\A)\G)(?:(?!</p>).)*?\K(<br>)
REPLACE BY: </p>
For this regex, I use generic formulas below as:
BSR = <p class="text_obisnuit">
FR = <br>
ESR = </p>

LIST OF GENERIC REGEX FORMULAS:
(?-si:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?s-i:(?!ESR).)*?\KFR

(BSR)\s*FR(.*?)FR\s*(ESR)

(?s-i)(?:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?:(?!ESR).)*?\K(FR)

(BSR.*?)(FR\s*ESR)

(?s-i)(?:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?:(?!ESR).)*?\K(FR)

(?:BSR|\G).*?\K(?:FR(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|ESR)

(?:BSR|\G).*?\K(?:FR(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(?:(?!ESR).)+?>)

(?:BSR|\G).*?\K(?:FR(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(?:(?!ESR1|ESR2).)+?>)

BSR(?:[^<]+|<(?!FR1|FR2))?</p>(*SKIP)(FAIL)|<(?!FR1|FR2)[^>]+>

BSR(?:[^<]+|<(?!FR))?</p>(*SKIP)(FAIL)|<(?!FR)[^>]+>

(?-s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?s-i:.*?ESR)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|FR

(?s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G).*?\K(?!ESR)

(?-si:BSR|(?!\\A)\\G)(?s-i:(?!ESR).)*?\\x20\\K(FR)

(?-si:BSR|(?!\\A)\\G)(?s-i:(?!ESR).)*?\\x20\\KFR(?=\\x20)

(?-si:BSR|(?!\\A)\\G)(?s-i:(?!ESR).)*?\\x20\\KFR

(?-si:BSR|(?!\\A)\\G)(?s-i:(?!ESR).)*?\\x20\\KFR(?=\\x20)

(?s-i)(?:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?:(?!ESR).)*?\K<(?!(?:FR1|FR2))[^>]*>

(?s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G).*?\K(?<=FR1)(.*?)(?=FR2)(?!ESR)

(?s)(?-i:BSR).*?(?<=FR1)(.*?)(?=FR2)(?=.*?ESR)

BSR[\s\S]+FR1\s+(\S+)\s+FR2[\s\S]+ESR   

(?s)(?<=BSR[\s\S]+FR1\s+)(\S+)(?=\s+FR2[\s\S]+ESR)

(?s)BSR[\s\S]+FR1\s+(\S+)\s+FR2[\s\S]+ESR

(?-s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?s-i:.*?ESR)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|FR

(?-s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G).*?\KFR(?!ESR)

(?-s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?s-i:(?!ESR).)*?\K(?-si:FR)

(?-s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G).*?\K(?-si:FR)(?=(?s-i:.*?ESR))

(?s)BSR(FR)(?-s).+ESR or BSR(FR).+(?s:(?=.*(ESR)))

(?s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G).*?\KFR(?!ESR)

(?s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?s-i:(?!ESR).)*?\K(?-si:FR)

(?s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G).*?\K(?-si:FR)(?=(?s-i:.*?ESR))

(?s)BSR(FR)(?-s).+ESR or BSR(FR).+(?s:(?=.*(ESR)))

(?-si:BSR|(?!\A)\G).*?\KFR(?!ESR)

(?-si:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?s-i:(?!ESR).)*?\K(?-si:FR)

(?-si:BSR|(?!\A)\G).*?\K(?-si:FR)(?=(?s-i:.*?ESR))

(?s)BSR(FR)(?-s).+ESR sau BSR(FR).+(?s:(?=.*(ESR)))

(?-s)(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G).*?\K(?-i:FR)(?=ESR)

(?-si:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?s-i:(?!ESR).)*?\K(FR)+

(?-i:BSR|\G(?!^))(?s:(?!ESR).)*?\K(?-i:FR)

BSR(?!\A)(?-s:.*?)\K(?-si:FR)(?=(?s-i:.*?ESR))

BSR\K.*?(?!\A)(?-s:.*?)\K(?-si:FR)(?=(?s-i:.*?ESR))

(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?s:(?!ESR).)*?\K(?-i:FR)   

(?-i:BSR|(?!^)\G)(?s:(?!ESR).)*?\K(?-i:FR)

(?s)\A.*BSR(FR)*ESR.*\z|\A.*BSR(FR)+ESR.*\z

(?s)\A.*BSR(FR)+ESR.*\z

(?s)\A.*BSR+(FR)+ESR.*\z

(?:BSR|\G)\S*\K(?:FR)(?=.*ESR)

(?:BSR|\G)\S*\K(FR)(?=.*ESR)

(?:BSR|\G)\S*\K(?:\h+FR)(?=.*ESR)

(?<!=\x20)(?<!=)FR(?!>|ESR|\x20>|\x20/>|\?>|\x20\?>|BSR)

(?<!=\x20)(?<!=)FR(?!>|ESR|\x20>|\x20/>|\?>|\x20\?>|\x20BSR)

(?<!=\x20)(?<!=)FR(?!>|ESR|\x20\?>|\x20BSR)

(?-is)^(?!.*BSR)(?!.*ESR)(?:(FR))

(?-is)^(?!.*BSR)(?!.*ESR)(?:(FR)(.+))

(BSR).*\K(?:\h+(FR))(?=.*ESR)

(?-i:BSR|\G(?!^))(?s:(ESR).)*?\K(?-i:FR)

(BSR)+(.)+\K(FR)(?s:(?=.*(ESR)))

(BSR)(FR)(.*?)(ESR)

(?s-i)^.+BSR\R|ESR.+|(?-s)^(FR)|(.+))$

(?s-i)^.+BSR\R|ESR.+|(?-s)^(FR)(.+))$

(BSR)(.*?)(FR)(.*?)(ESR)

(?s)(?-i:(BSR).+?ESR|\G(?!^))((?!(ESR)).)*?\K(FR)

(?s)(?-i:BSR.+?ESR|\G(?!^))((?!ESR).)*?\KFR

(BSR)+(.)+\K(FR)(?=.*ESR)

(BSR)+(.)+\K(FR)(?=.*)(ESR)

(BSR)*\K(?:(FR))(?=.*ESR)

(BSR)\K(?-s)(.*?)\KFR(?=.*ESR)

.*?(BSR)(?-s)(.*?)(FR).*(.*ESR)

(BSR).*(\b(FR)\b.*).*(ESR)

(?:BSR|\G).*?\K(?:FR(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(?!ESR)[^>]*>)

BSR(?=(?:(?!ESR).)*?FR).+?ESR\R?

BSR(?=(?:(?!FR).)*?FR).+?ESR\R?

BSR(?=(?:(?!ESR).)*?FR)(?=(?:(?!ESR).)*?FR).+?ESR\R?

BSR(?=(?:(?!ESR).)*?FR)(?=(?:(?!ESR).)).+?ESR\R?

(?s)(?:BSR|\G)(?:(?!ESR).)*?\K(FR)

(?s)(?:BSR|\G(?!^))(?:(?!ESR).)*?\KFR

(?!BSR)*\K(?!BSR)(?:(FR)))(?=.*ESR)

(?s)(?:BSR|\G)(?:(?!ESR).)*?\K(?:FR)

(?s)(?:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?:(?!ESR).)*?\KFR

(?s)(?:BSR|\G).*?\K(?:FR(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(?:(?!ESR).)+?>)

(?:BSR|\G).*?\K(?:FR(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(?:(?!ESR).)+?>)

(?:BSR|\G).*?\K).*?(FR)(?=.*ESR)

(?:BSR|\G).*?\K)(FR).*?(?=.*ESR)

(?:BSR|\G)(FR).*?\K).*?(?=.*ESR)

(?s-i)(?:BSR|\G)(?:(?!ESR).)*?\K(FR)

(?:BSR|\G)(FR).*?(FR)\K).*?(?=.*ESR)

(?s-i)(?:<p[^>]*>|(?!\A)\G)(?:(?!</p>).)*?\K<(?!(?:/[ap]>|a\x20[^>]+>))[^>]*>

(?s-i)(?:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?:(?!ESR).)*?\K<(?!(?:FR1|FR2))[^>]*>

(?:BSR|\G).*?\K(?:FR(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(?:(?!ESR).)+?>)

(?:BSR|\G).*?\K(?:FR(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<(?:(?!ESR1|ESR2).)+?>)

BSR(?:[^<]+|<(?!FR1|FR2))?ESR(*SKIP)(FAIL)|<(?!FR1|FR2)[^>]+>

SPECIFICATIONS:
Let BSR ( Begin Search-region Regex ) be the regex which defines the beginning of the area where the search for FR, must start
Let ESR ( End Search-region Regex) be the regex which defines, implicitly, the area where the search for FR, must end
Let FR (Find Regex ) be the regex which defines the char, string or expression to be searched
Let RR (Replacement Regex ) be the regex which defines the char, string or expression which must replace the FR expression. REPLACE RR (means can be \1 \2 ...or $1 $2 or other

I use first Generic formula: (BSR.*?)(FR\s*ESR)
BSR = <p class="text_obisnuit">
FR = <br>
ESR = </p>


Ctrl+H
Find what: (<p class="text_obisnuit">.*?)(<br>\s*</p>)
Replace with: \1</p>
CHECK Wrap around
CHECK Regular expression
UNCHECK . matches newline
Replace all

